# failed to retrievie values from php cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I have **2** files, **index.php** and **content.php** ...

I am **setting** a cookie on the `content.php` but when i am trying to retrieve that cookie in `index.php`, it says `undefined index`...

I dnt know the reason of this `error` !

I am using this code for setting the cookie-

```
$loader = $_GET['id'];
$expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
setcookie("loader", $loader, $expire);
```

and this for retriving-

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["loader"])) echo $_COOKIE["loader"];
else echo "no cookie found !";
```

Please Help Me Guys !

Comment: show your full error.

Comment: You shouldn't get an error if you have the `isset()` check.

Comment: In the script that sets the cookie, make sure you haven't output anything before calling `setcookie()`.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя He said they're two different pages -- content.php and index.php.

Comment: @Barmar thats what i am saying, i have successfully set the cookie, coz i can see it from the **opera's cookie manager** but when trying to get the data in the **index.php** then it says undefined index :(

Comment: i have said everything @YogeshSuthar

Comment: Undefined index.. isn't an error. there's missing a part. Anyway see my edit.

Comment: seen and it worked @KeesSonnema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit2:

If you get this error 'Undefined Index' that means that your $_GET['id'] isn't set properly. Make sure you've set the $_GET['id']; when setting the cookie.

```
$loader = $_GET['id'];
$expire=time()+60*60*24*365;

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
setcookie("loader", $loader, $expire, '/');
}else{
echo 'no cookie set';
```

Edit:

when you've set the cookie you first have to refresh the page BEFORE you read it. otherwise the cookie isn't sent in the header.

---

Just add a path to your cookie like this:

```
$loader = $_GET['id'];
$expire=time()+60*60*24*365;
setcookie("loader", $loader, $expire, '/');
```

NOTE: I've added the `'/'`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This shouldn't be needed if both scripts are in the same directory.

Comment: I am almost 100% sure it has to do with the path. because the browser uses the script uri, so you can always see the cookie if set. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7394471/1379394

Comment: @KeesSonnema as i have in the above replies, i have succesfully set the `cookie` i can view it in the **opera's cookie manager**...

Comment: As i said. the browser can always read the cookie even if it is not available in the views. that's because it is using the script uri.

Comment: @KeesSonnema : i have set the `/path` and it worked... thanx bud ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    setcookie('loader',$_REQUEST['id'],time()+60*60*24*365, '/');   
} else {
    setcookie('loader','',time()-3600, '/');
    unset($_COOKIE['loader']);          
}


if(isset($_COOKIE['loader']) && $_COOKIE['loader'] != "") {     
    echo $_COOKIE['loader'];
} else {
   echo "no cookie found !";
}
```

Comment: i have successfully set the cookie, coz i can see it from the **opera's cookie manager** but when trying to get the data in the **index.php** then it says undefined index

Comment: @vikram This is working fine..i myself have tried it.It can be a problem of PHP Version.What version you are using?

Comment: i am using PHP Version 5.3.9, anyways Ritika i got my answer... thanx for commenting.... :-)